# Web3.js not receiving events from contract

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js

My `ProjectFactory` smart contract emits this event:

```
event ProjectCreated(address indexed creator, address projectAddress);

function createProject(...) public {
  ...
  emit ProjectCreated(msg.sender, newProject); 
}
```

In my Nextjs component, I can clearly see the events that have been emitted so far:

```
const pastEvents = await factory.getPastEvents('ProjectCreated', {
  fromBlock: 0,  
  toBlock: 'latest'
});
console.log(pastEvents);
```

But as I try to listen and react to them (routing, etc.).. I don't get any. No errors either:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (web3) {
      const waitForProjectCreated = async () => {
        const factory = Factory(web3);

        console.log('Listening for ProjectCreated events');  // gets printed
        factory.once('ProjectCreated', {}, (err, event) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log('error:', err);  // never printed
          } else {
            console.log('event:', event);  // never printed
          }
        });

        // router.push(`/projects/${event.returnValues.projectAddress}`);
      };
      waitForProjectCreated();
    }
    };
  }, [web3]);
```

The `Factory` constructor is simple, and I successfully use that contract everywhere else:

```
const Factory = (web3) => {
  return new web3.eth.Contract(
    compiledProjectFactory.abi,
    '0x...'
  );
};
```

I tried several different ways, incl.

```
factory.events.ProjectCreated({}, (err, event) => { ... });
```

Nothing works. The block receipt(s) clearly show the event being emitted:
https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0xc0ac05fea32d4b4c60a70813656d9926cb4995812009c43d9e21799734e46aba#eventlog

Am I setting up the listener in a wrong way/place?